# Animate Crane in forge viewer on RVT models

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

Our team is currently working on a 4D simulation within the Forge Viewer. Our current focus involves coloring elements based on specific dates. Simultaneously, we aim to create an animated effect where a crane moves into the corresponding area. We kindly request your guidance on how to accomplish this. Could you please provide us with best practices or suggestions for implementing this feature effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Coloring design elements to indicate things like scheduling status is straightforward. Here's a live demo that shows this kind of functionality: https://aps-phasing-poc.autodesk.io, and the source code is here: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-phasing-poc.

As for the crane animations: the viewer APIs allow you to manipulate the loaded 3D models to a certain degree, for example, applying custom matrix transformations to individual elements as explained in [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/know-how-complex-component-transformations-viewer-part-1-basics). Another option you might want to consider is adding the crane as a vanilla three.js object ([yet another blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer)), and animate it using the standard three.js capabilities.